# Let $p$ be a prime and $k$a positive ingeger such that $a^k=a (mod p)$ for all integers a. prove that $p-1$divides $k-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Attempt : by Fermat's little theorem we can obtain following equaility
$$ a^{k-1}=e=a^{p-1}  $$ (mod $p$)

Now, by devision algorithm

$k-1=(p-1)q+r $

$(0 \le r \lt p-1)$

then 
$$a^{k-1}=a^{(p-1)q+r}$$

$$=a^{(p-1)q}a^r$$

$$=a^r=e (mod p)$$
I want to show $r$ must be zero but I 'm lack of information about $r$ 
can you give me more hint ?
I'd appreciate for hint in any other way than my method

Comment: +1 for showing your line of reasoning for that makes it easier to pinpoint the problem. You really need to use the fact that he congruence $a^k\equiv a\pmod p$ holds for **ALL** $a$. Otherwise the claim is false. Consider the prime $p=7$, $a=2$ for an example: $a^4=16\equiv 2=a\pmod 7$ suggesting that $k-1=3<p-1=6$ might work. When $p=7$ only with $a=3$ or $a=5$ will we reach the finish line. This also makes the problem a bit more difficult in the sense that we don't know which $a$ to use.

Comment: (cont'd) As suggested by Carl Schildkraut (+1) using the existence of a primitive root modulo $p$ is one way. But, for that solution to be helpful, you need to be familiar with the result. Have you covered that piece of theory, yet? If not, then as an alternative you can use the fact that the residue classes of integers modulo $p$ form a field. Have you covered that?

Comment: I think there was a TeX-typo in your first displayed  equation. You need `a^{k-1}` instead of `a^k-1` to keep all of $k-1$ as the exponent. Please verify!

Comment: I studied about primitive root in elementary number theory class. but I 'd rather recall the concept instead of using your recommend about latter case. because it is awkward to me.

Comment: That's fine. The choice of approach really depends on your background. So if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, set $a=g$ and see where that leads.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  if $a$ has primitive root for modulo $p$, then $\phi(p)=p-1 $ must divide $k-1$ then I obtain the result right? but if $a$ doesn't have  a primitive root, how can I get the result ?

Comment: since our assumption is for all $a$ , we can just consider that $a$ has primitive root. so in case of that, We obtain $p-1$ must divide $k-1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $a^r\equiv 1\bmod p$ for all $a\not\equiv 0\bmod p$ (I'm assuming that what you've proven, I find it a bit hard to follow your argument exactly), what happens when $a$ is a primitive root $\bmod p$? When is a power of a primitive root $\equiv 1\bmod p$?

Comment: Can this be proved without using the primitive root?